# Obtain the value of a symbol in an equation using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to obtain the values of 4 different variables while given the following equation:

f(t)=k1*t+k2*(t^2)+k3*(c^(t*0.15))

I'm also given the following results:
f(10)=25; f(15)=130; f(20)=650

I'm trying to use sympy's solve() in python, to obtain these values for the unknown variables (the k's and c) and I'm employing the equation when t=10

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import math
import sys

def Find(t):
 k1 = symbols(' k1')
 k2 = symbols(' k2')
 k3 = symbols(' k3')
 c = symbols(' c')
 eq1 = Eq((k1*t)+(k2*(t**2))+(k3*(c**(0.15*t)))==25)
 sol = solve((eq1), (k1, k2, k3, c))
 num =  {sol[k1]}
 print(num)
 



while(1):
  print("\nValues of variables")
  t = 10
  Find(t)
  print("\nEnd")
  sys.exit()
```

My problem lies in which I can't get the value of k1 while trying to reference it in {sol[k1]}. If I keep k1 as the index I get this message

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol
```

And if I attempt to replace it with a 0, or any number for that matter, I have this message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run you're code `print(sol)`, You will get output `[]` which is empty list and `k1` is not an index its an object so you can't use `k1` for indexing. Hence the error.

Does this work as solution ?

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
import math
import sys

def Find(t, v):
    k1, k2, k3, c = symbols('k1'), symbols('k2'), symbols('k3'), symbols('c')
    eq1 = Eq((k1 * t) + (k2 * (t ** 2)) + (k3 * (c ** (0.15 * t))), v)
    sol = solve(eq1, [k1, k2, k3, c])
    return sol

print("\nValues of variables")
t, v = 10, 25
sol = Find(t, v)[0]

print(f"k1 = {sol[0]}")
print(f"k2 = {sol[1]}")
print(f"k3 = {sol[2]}")
print(f"c = {sol[3]}")
```

Gives Output

```
Values of variables
k1 = -0.1*c**(3/2)*k3 - 10.0*k2 + 2.5
k2 = k2
k3 = k3
c = c
```

If you run it for each symbol like this

```
def Find(t, v):
    k1, k2, k3, c = symbols('k1'), symbols('k2'), symbols('k3'), symbols('c')
    eq1 = Eq((k1 * t) + (k2 * (t ** 2)) + (k3 * (c ** (0.15 * t))), v)
    sol = solve(eq1, k1), solve(eq1, k2), solve(eq1, k3), solve(eq1, c)
    return sol

print("\nValues of variables")
t, v = 10, 25
sol = Find(t, v)

print(f"k1 = {sol[0]}")
print(f"k2 = {sol[1]}")
print(f"k3 = {sol[2]}")
print(f"c = {sol[3]}")
```

You get this as output

```
Values of variables
k1 = [-0.1*c**(3/2)*k3 - 10.0*k2 + 2.5]
k2 = [-0.01*c**(3/2)*k3 - 0.1*k1 + 0.25]
k3 = [5.0*(-2.0*k1 - 20.0*k2 + 5.0)/c**(3/2)]
c = [16.1582601752391*(-0.577350269189626*(-0.1*k1/k3 - k2/k3 + 0.25/k3)**0.333333333333333 - I*(-0.1*k1/k3 - k2/k3 + 0.25/k3)**0.333333333333333)**2, 16.1582601752391*(-0.577350269189626*(-0.1*k1/k3 - k2/k3 + 0.25/k3)**0.333333333333333 + I*(-0.1*k1/k3 - k2/k3 + 0.25/k3)**0.333333333333333)**2, 21.5443469003188*(-0.1*k1/k3 - k2/k3 + 0.25/k3)**(2/3)]
```